# How to create or enhance a custom annotation that uses mapstruct

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, mapstruct

Mapsturct has @Mapping annotation with predefined attributes 
eg: `@Mapping(source="", target="", qualifiedByName="")` , what if i want to add another attribute it and use it to compute the logic

eg: `@Mapping(source="", target="", qualifiedByName="" , version="")`

I would like to pass the version number to it and depending on the version, it would set the target from source.

I tried to create a custom annotation and use @Mapping in it but didnt help

```
@CustomMapping(version = "1.0", mapping = @Mapping(source = "", target = "", qualifiedByName=""))
```

Comment: Can you provide some example of how the mapping code would look like? I am not understanding what you mean depending on the version?

Comment: This would be the normal mapping which we do mapping from source to target
    `@Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount")
    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car)`. In this @Mapping annotation I want add a version field which we tell whether this mapping is support for version 1 or version 2, eg: `@Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount", version=2) ` means map this field only if version is 2 and not when version = 1

Comment: I was also thinking of creating another custom annotation with version and mapping attribute, and this annotation processor will delegate to mapstruct Mapping if version is 2 but not sure how to do or achieve this one..

Comment: How do you know whether it is version 1 or 2?

Comment: Lets say its defined like this `@Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount", version=2)`, this version value would come from properties or request , and if version is 2  do this mapping, i can do it using qualifiedByName or expression, but looking to extend this mapping annotation or create custom annotation like `@CustomMapping(version = "1.0", mapping = @Mapping(source = "", target = "", qualifiedByName=""))` to achieve this . It would be really helpful to get some ideas on how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define a 2nd distinct annotation to be used alongside `@Mapping`?

```
@Mapping(source="", target="", qualifiedByName="")
@MappingVersion("1.0")
CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
```

If your concern is that you want some kind of enforcement that version is always present when `@Mapping` is used then you could trivially [write an annotation processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder) which does this at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, if mappingversion need to be added then I have to write an annotation processor that will do the logic before calling Mapping of mapstruct

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the question I understand a bit more what needs to be done. Basically based on some input parameter different mapping methods need to be created.

Not sure how complex your logic is. However, what you can do is to create your own annotation processor that would be able to create MapStruct mappers.

Let's imagine that you have

```
@CustomMapper
public interface MyMapper {
    @CustomMapping(version = "1.0", mappings = { 
        @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount", qualifiedByName="")
    })
    @CustomMapping(version = "2.0", mappings = { 
        @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seats", qualifiedByName="")
    })
    CarDto map(Car car, String version);
}
```

So your annotation processor would need to handle `CustomMapper`.

The processor would also generate the different MapStruct versioned interfaces.

So:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapperV1 {

    @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount", qualifiedByName="")
    CarDto map(Car car)
}

@Mapper
public interface MyMapperV2 {

    @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seats", qualifiedByName="")
    CarDto map(Car car)
}
```

And additionally an implementation of `MyMapper`. That looks like:

```
public class MyMapperImpl {

    protected MyMapperV1 myMapperV1 = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapperV1.class):
    protected MyMapperV2 myMapperV2 = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapperV2.class):

    public CarDto map(Car car, String version) {
        if ("1.0".equals(version)) {
            return myMapperV1.map(car);
        } else {
            return myMapperV2.map(car);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the goal is to have your processor generate the interfaces that would be picked up by MapStruct in the same compilation round. This is possible with annotation processing.

Another option is to write the MapStruct mappers on your own and in the caller place pick the one which is appropriate for the version. This might be simpler actually.

Comment: thanks a lot Filip for putting actually what i want, but not sure how to implement it i will to write an annotation processor that would create different MapStruct versioned interfaces. How would second option work how to write mapstruct mappers ?

Comment: Well the second option is that your write `MyMapperV1` and `MyMapperV2` manually by yourself, like any other MapStruct mapper and then when you need to call it you would call the appropriate one

Comment: By first option it will be very difficult as in my current interface i have annotated it with with `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, uses={Class1.class, class2.class} `. Also have lot of methods with mapping like `@Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seats", qualifiedByName="formatSeatsValue")`. So if i wrote custom annotation processor then i have to generate MyMapperV1 with all the mappings that would be difficult and using @CustomMapper annotation in place of @mapper annotation will be lot messy

Comment: Oh currently I have lot of mappers and each mapper has lot of methods in it, so creating multiple mappers of v1, v2 will be difficult to maintain, is any way to support version would be really helpful as I am trying to use it for supporting api versioning where some clients would support 10 fields others would require 20 fields. If able to add version to each Mapping would be really good and easy to understand and maintain, is there any way I could extend Mapping processor to hook version attribute to it